# How can I use a user's input in my countdown ios application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, countdown

I would like to collect a date from the user, convert it to unix epoch time and use that epoch time stamp to replace the time stamp that follows the dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: in my code. Any assistance is greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
-(void)updatelabel{
    NSCalendar *Calender = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    int units = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [Calender components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:destinationDate options:0];
    [dateLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c  %d%c  %d%c  %d%c", [components day], 'd', [components hour], 'h',   [components minute], 'm', [components second], 's']];  
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    destinationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1356088260];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updatelabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: I would like to collect a date from the user, convert it to unix epoch time and use that epoch time stamp to replace the time stamp that follows the dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to collect a date from a user, the easiest way is to use a UIDatePicker.  Assuming you are using Storyboards or NIBs, you'd drag the control from the Object Library and connect its "Value Changed" event with an action method.

[image: UIDatePicker]

Inside your action method, you could grab the date as:

```
- (IBAction)dateSelected:(UIDatePicker *)picker {
    NSDate *selectedDate = picker.date;
    // ...
}
```

If, instead, you have an NSString from the user, you can use an NSDateFormatter to convert the string to an NSDate:

```
NSString *usersDateStr = @"12/01/2012" // this would be retrieved from the user.
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";
NSDate *selectedDate = [formatter dateFromString:usersDateStr];
```

Either way, once you have a date object, if needed, you can convert it to an NSTimeInterval with:

```
NSTimeInterval time = [selectedDate timeIntervalSince1970];
```